# Searching for label by NDC

Tags: openfda

I'm trying to use the label API to search for a specific OTC drug.  Lets take CVS's 10mg Loratadine for example.  The NDC number is 59779-612-75.

Based on the API docs I think the right query should be:

https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.product_ndc:59779-612-75&limit=100

That returns several hundred results, none of which have a openfda.product_ndc field that matches.  Most are substrings or similar strings.  The correct product is in there, but the product_ndc doesn't match.  The package_ndc field (which isn't documented) does.

None of the variations on NDC substring seem to work either, all return several hundred results:
    `https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.product_ndc:59779-612&limit=100`
    `https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.package_ndc:59779-612-75&limit=100`
    `https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.package_ndc:59779-612&limit=100`

A lookup on the following site returns exactly one correct match:
http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/ndc/dsp_searchresult.cfm

Am I missing something or is the API behaving a bit strangely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you use quotes around the product_ndc field it should give you the results you are looking for.

```
https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.product_ndc:"59779-612"&limit=100
```

Link for reference:

https://open.fda.gov/api/reference/#exact-matches

Comment: Yeah, that does work.  Just strange that it treats the pieces of the NDC code as partial string matches rather than using the entire NDC code.  If I search for "hotdog" I don't get results for "hot" or "h".  Is it the hyphen triggering that behavior?

Comment: That I don't know, and that is a good point. I think it may have been setup like that more for when people search for names of drugs, almost like a fuzzy search. It could also be elastic search behavior and not a programmatic decision.